# Regarding usage of sparse matrix as an input in Fselector package

Tags: r, feature-extraction, fselector

I am using information.gain(), chi.squared() and gain. Ratio() functions provided by Fselector package for feature selection.

All these functions are accepting data frame as an input,
 as I am using matrix of dimension  200161(rows), 323(Column) data set ,Getting  error

```
error in jnew(name): java.lang.outofMemoryError: java heap space R
```

I have xeon preocessor, with 8 GB RAM, and after expanding the memory limit to max to assert by using 
command

```
memory.limit()
```

results in 8026,which is also not sufficient

For memory efficiency i have converted data frame to Sparse matrix

Now the question is, can we use sparse matrix as an input to functions information.gain(), chi.squared() and gain.ratio()

Please anyone help regarding this,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported at the moment, sorry.